# Check Graph Reciprocity using Pandas

Tags: pandas, graph

I have a Graph loaded in pandas and I want to check if my graph has nodes with reciprocity. My dataset looks like this:

| id | from | to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | s01 | s03 |
| 1 | s02 | s01 |
| 2 | s03 | s01 |

The desired output of my code is the reciprocal nodes: (s01, s03)

I found a solution transforming my dataframe into tuples and comparing each combination of my nodes, but I'm sure this solution is far from ideal. Following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
    
    t1 = list(zip(input_table_1['from'], input_table_1['to']))
    t2 = list(zip(input_table_1['to'], input_table_1['from']))
    
    r = [] #reciprocity nodes
    for tuple_1 in t1:
        for tuple_2 in t2:
            if tuple_2 == tuple_1 and (tuple_2 not in r and tuple_2[::-1] not in r):
                r.append(tuple_2)
    
    output_table_1 = pd.DataFrame(r, columns=['from', 'to'])
```

Is there a way to do that checking only using pandas structure?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can merge the DataFrame with itself after swapping the from and to columns in the right DataFrame. Then `sort` the merged result and drop duplicates to get the unique pairs of reciprocal nodes.

```
res = df[['from', 'to']].merge(df[['from', 'to']].rename(columns={'from': 'to', 'to': 'from'}))

pd.DataFrame(np.sort(res.to_numpy()), columns=['node1', 'node2']).drop_duplicates()
#  node1 node2
#0   s01   s03
```